# SSIS 2012 Send SSIS logs via Send Mail task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

My package is using logging to store details of package execution on a Text file. The Send Mail task is the last task in the Control Flow. What I want to accomplish is to have the logs sent via email so users are alerted of package execution results. I already set `Delay Validation` to True, but I always get:

> [Send Mail Task] Error: Either the file "\ushou16p101\GROUPS\Data\View_log.txt" does not exist or you do not have permissions to access the file.

The file is stored in a shared folder in which I do have valid permissions. Tried different suggestions offered online but nothing works. If I remove the logging option so it doesn't generate the log Text file, then, package runs OK and sends email, of course the log attached to the email would contain the previous execution and this is not what I want.

Comment: did you forget to close the log file after it was completed? Could you share the package steps?

Comment: Since it is the actual package's logs, how can I close them?

Comment: Are you running this in a SQL Agent job? I suggest you add a SQL Agent step after that sends the log after the package is complete. For example something that calls `blat.exe`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `\` in the UNC path at the beginning. i.e. should your path be `\\ushou16p101\..` and not `\ushou16p101\..` (as seen in the error message)